# How to grep any values by tipe at sed

Tags: curl, sed, grep

I have some values:

```
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2275-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2273-saphana-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2274-saphana-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2275-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2276-saphana-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2277-develop.zip
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2278-saphana-develop.zip
```

How I can `grep` last build with only (without saphana-develop), for example:

```
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2277-develop.zip
```

This expressions writes at file only hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2278-saphana-develop.zip

```
$ curl -s http://<ip address>:8081/artifactory/hybris-snapshot-local/| sed -rn "s/.*Platform-(.*\develop.*)\.zip.*/\1/p" | sort | grep develop | tail -1 | tr -d "\n" > /opt/test1.out
```

Comment: change your `grep develop` into `grep -v 'saphana'`

Comment: You can simply reverse the result using `tac` and get the first matching entry not containing `saphana-develop` as below. You can guarantee on first match and exit with the `-m1` flag

`.. | tac | grep -m1 '[0-9]*[0-9]-develop.zip$'`

Answer (score 1):

Please change the grep expression as `grep -v saphana-develop | tail -1` which will only prints the last modified one without saphana-develop

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you want this command:

```
▶ grep -v saphana-develop FILE | sort -k3 -t- -V | tail -1 
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2277-develop.zip
```

Whereas you would probably replace the grep with

```
▶ curl -s http://<ip address>:8081/artifactory/hybris-snapshot-local/ | \
    grep develop | grep -v saphana | sort -k3 -t- -V | tail -1
```

although it's not entirely clear.

Explanation:

- Using the Unix `sort` command, I specified `-k3` (field 3) and `-t-` (delimiter character `-`) and `-V` - a version sort so that the sorting by the version string is worked out for you.
- Use `grep -v saphana` to filter out the string you don't want, as noted by others.
- Based on what you're doing with it, it appears you don't need the `sed` command at all.

Answer (score 0):

SO many options including a couple I don't see mentioned so far in other answers:

```
$ grep '[0-9]-d' file | tail -1
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2277-develop.zip

$ awk -F'-' 'NF<5{v=$0} END{print v}' file
hybrisServer-Platform-1.1.2277-develop.zip
```